# Python how to convert TimeSpan string to DateTime Day

Tags: python, datetime

```
42.00:00:00
```

This is a TimeSpan value from PowerShell.

How should I go about converting the above string into Python DateTime? I actually only need the day value in a string. The following code does not work with this:

`strptime("42.00:00:00", "%d.%H:%M:%S")`

I'm assuming it's because of the day being out of day of the month range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need the day value, you can just split the string on the period, and take the first element.

```
timespan = "42.00:00:00"
num_days = int(timespan.split(".", 1)[0])
```

The issue in the conversion you're trying to do is that the PowerShell Timespan is a period of time, and isn't equivalent to a DateTime object though which represents a specific date and time. Instead, you want to convert it to a [timedelta object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), which also represents a span of time.

So from this code, you can create that object with the following:

```
from datetime import timedelta
timedelta(days=num_days)
```

Comment: I already tried what you suggested and it worked. I was just searching for something more explicit I think.

Comment: What do you mean more explicit?

Comment: I was wondering if there was an equivalent to TimeSpan in Python. It's not DateTime because of its "23:59:59.999999" time limit.

Comment: As I said in my answer, the equivalent to a TimeSpan in Python is a timedelta object.

Comment: But it's not possible to go directly to timedelta? So without the split.

Comment: If there was a more "direct" way, it would probably internally do the same thing.